# Where's the error? Code for password entry in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, passwords

I'm a beginner. After the execution of this simple password code, it keeps showing invalid even after entering the correct password. Anyone out there who can help me out?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string username;
    int password[4]={0},i,realname[4]={1,2,4,8},j,temp=0;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        cout<<"\nUsername: ";
        cin>>username;
        if(username=="admin")
        {
            temp++;
        }
        cout<<"\nPassword: ";
        for (i = 0; i < 4;i++)
        {
            password[i]=getch();
            cout<<"*";
            if(password[i]==realname[i])
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
        if(temp==5)
        {
            cout<<"Login Success!";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nInvalid username or password.";
            j=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Idea: Print `temp` after every time you change it to see what's going on.

Comment: Debug and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Also `conio.h` is C, not C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving you `Invalid username or password` it is because the value of `temp` is never update inside the `for` loop. The line `if(password[i]==realname[i])` is evaluating to `false` because it is trying to compare the ascii representation of the user input which are¨[49, 50, 51, 52] to realname[1, 2, 4, 8] array.  Either you have to convert the user input to an `int` or make the password and the realname `char` type.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string username;
    int i, j, temp=0;
    char realname[4]={'1', '2', '4', '8'};
    char password[4] = {'0'};
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        cout<<"\nUsername: ";
        cin>>username;
        if(username=="admin"){
            temp++;
        }
        cout<<"\nPassword: ";
        for (i = 0; i < 4;i++)
        {
            password[i]=static_cast<char>(getch());
            cout<<"*";
            if(password[i]==realname[i])
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
        std::cout<< "\n";
        if(temp == 5)
        {
            cout<<"Login Success!\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nInvalid username or password\n.";
            j=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I change the username and password to be character arrays?

Comment: You could do that. It is also possible to use `atoi` or  `stoi` functions to convert user input to an `int`.